# Absolute Names in Angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am looking to clarify this case mentioned in [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names) ->

```
$stateProvider
  .state('contacts.detail', {
    views: {

        // absolutely targets the 'status' view in root unnamed state.
        // <div ui-view='status'/> within index.html
        "status@" : {
                    templateUrl: layout.html,
                    controller : 'MainController as vm'
         }


  });
```

So in this case if by mistake i end up defining another state which has a similar views object for example -

```
$stateProvider
  .state('contacts.detail1', {
    views: {

        // absolutely targets the 'status' view in root unnamed state.
        // <div ui-view='status'/> within index.html
        "status@" : {
                    templateUrl: layout1.html,
                    controller : 'MainController1 as vm'
         }


  });
```

Then will there be a clash in choosing the template, controller to assign to ui-view="status" element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there will not be any clash. Define your ui-router code as follows

```
$stateProvider
  .state('contacts.detail', {
    url: '.detail',
    views: {
      "status@" : {
        templateUrl: layout.html,
        controller : 'MainController as vm'
       }
    }).state('contacts.detail1', {
    url: '.detail1',
    views: {
        "status@" : {
            templateUrl: layout1.html,
            controller : 'MainController1 as vm'
         }
  });
```

But there should be one contacts state also.
Url for first one will be `/contacts.detail` and for 2nd `/contacts.detail1`

Comment: in case there is not url mentioned and the state has abstract = true then?